# How can I create a div with content that overlays my slider?

Tags: html, css

I have a slider with 3 slides in my hero section , I want to create a div with content that is placed and displays over the 3 slides, and always shows regardless of what slide I'm on.

Comment: show your code please

Comment: So a fixed position element.

Comment: @09eric09 Please consider [accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/321916) on your questions, that solved your problems or feel free to ask for more help and provide more details, if none of them helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an absolutely positioned element that sits on top of the slider.

This can be achieved by placing a wrapper element around your slider and then adding the absolutely placed element inside the wrapper next to the slider.

```
<style>
  .slider-wrapper {
    /* required so the absolutely positioned overlay is placed relative to this wrapper */
    position: relative; 
  }

  .slider-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    /* center this overlay over the slider */
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
</style>

<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-overlay">
    This content will be displayed over the slider
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  .slider-wrapper {
    position: relative;
  }
  .slider-wrapper .slider-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(134, 134, 134, 0.2);
  }
</style>
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider-overlay">`enter code here`
    This content will be displayed over the slider
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although this could theoretically be the answer it is not best practice to just post a code snippet. Provide some context and explanation. For further information refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

CSS codes:

```
#hero {
  position: relative;
}
#topdiv,
#sliders {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#infoi {
  z-index: 10;
}
```

HTML codes:

```
<div id="hero">
  <div id="topdiv">Div content</div>
  <div id="sliders">
    <div>Slider1 Content</div>
    <div>Slider2 Content</div>
    <div>Slider3 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```